# Android X,Y determination of an Image

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, coordinates

I am using the following xml for Layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:paddingBottom="20dip"
    tools:context=".ZoneSelectionActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:text="@string/affected_zone" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/imageHolder"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#0B3861"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/subsegment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:contentDescription="subsegment"
                android:src="@drawable/sub_segment01" />

    </FrameLayout>  

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my screen-shot. I want to the coordinate of the marked point(x,y of top-left corner of the image) in the screen. How it can be determine?

[image: Screen-shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int coords[] = {0,0};
yourImageView.getLocationOnScreen(coords);
int x = coords[0];
int y = coords[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `View.getLocationOnScreen()`.You can only invoke it AFTER layout phase.

Comment: What do you mean by "AFTER layout phase";

Comment: @dev_android  don't call this method before the views are positioned on screen

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure ImageView provides a way to get the location of its image on screen.

You can only query the location of the ImageView itself.

Try using ImageView.getImageMatrix() but I'm not sure if it's populated when the image is centered (not scaled)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
View v;
int x = v.getLeft();
int y = v.getTop();
```

Comment: It will not work. It will just give the distance w.r.t. the parent view.

Comment: you were asking the x,y coordinate right? my answer is the x,y coordinate in pixels

Comment: Test it, it will not give proper value.